# Combine Referenced DataTables in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm new to C# and my current code seems a bit of a hack-  how can I keep combining referenced datatables more efficiently (less lines of code), or at least more readable?

(I have no say in the framework, BTW, I'm playing it as it lies ;))

1. I lose the last datatable once I reference it again
2. I can't import rows into a datatable that doesn't share the same schema.

This code address both issues, but man, it seems fugly.

```
DataTable dt_ref = new DataTable();
DataTable dt_final = new DataTable();
bool datatable_is_cloned;
String[] customer_ids = {"cust_a", "cust_b", "cust_c"}

foreach(String id in customer_ids)
{
    if(!obj_cust.Select_by_customer_id(id, ref dt_ref, ref error_msg))
    {
        //do error handling     
    } 

    if(!datatable_is_cloned)
    {
        dt_final = dt_ref.Clone();
        datatable_is_cloned = true;
    }

    foreach(DataRow r in dt_ref.Rows)
        dt_final.ImportRow(r); 
 }
```

Edited for clarity.

Problem is is every time I loop and hit the database with another customer id, my dt_ref loses all of its previous results and gains merely the new ones (yes, this is expected behavior).

I want to keep a running total of all the results from select method.

Comment: You should ask this here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ !!

Comment: I don't understand the `if (!datatable_is_cloned)` part. Why don't you clone the table at the beginning? Note that `Clone` only copies the columns not the data. Therefore you would use `Copy` instead.

Comment: if you clone why should they have different schemas? And if they don't have the same schema why should they be in the same datatable?

Comment: Maybe you should explain better what you're trying to do. It's not clear. You haven't even mentioned `lst_customers` and why you loop it. You're not really using the customers.

Comment: I don't clone at the beginning because the datatable does not have the schema *until* it's been referenced and populated.  I can't import rows into datatables with dissimilar schemas.

Comment: "And if they don't have the same schema why should they be in the same datatable?"  A new datatable has no schema, hence it's different than the referenced one.  So until both have the same schema, I can't import rows from one to the other.